# PokerStars LogFile Stacksize parsing

Tags: poker-tools

I know how to read your own hand from the Pokerstars.log.0 file.
But how do I get the information of each stacksize from each player?
I don't mean in HandHistory, I mean in Live hand.
Tools like Jivaro display the stacksize from other player, so there must be a way to read it out.